# PowerShell Script - Where-Object less than

Tags: powershell, object

I am writing a script to check the expiry date of some certificates. I have written a base script to get the details which needed, but I am now looking to get just those which are showing certificates expiring in the next 30 days.

```
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '<URL>'  -TimeoutSec 60 
$result2a = ($result.RawContent) -split '\n' | Select-String -Pattern 'Certificate\s+Fine:(.+)::.*Expiry\s+Days=\((\d+)\s+days\)' | 
Foreach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Certificate = $_.matches.Groups[1].Value
        Days        = $_.matches.Groups[2].Value -as [int]
    }
}
$result2a
```

This will then print the following:

```
Certificate                                                                                                                                                          Days
-----------                                                                                                                                                          ----
denmark_24032023.pem                                                                                                                                                  598
denmark_new.pem                                                                                                                                                      3049
edi_maerskline_com_belgium_chain_14122021.pem                                                                                                                         133
edi_maerskline_com_belgium_key_14122021.pem                                                                                                                           133
edi_maerskline_com_cert_09202021.pem                                                                                                                                   46
edi_maerskline_com_chain_09202021_dec.pem                                                                                                                              46
edi_maerskline_com_chain_09202021.pem                                                                                                                                  46
finland_cert_04022022.pem                                                                                                                                             184
finland_chain_04022022.pem                                                                                                                                            184
finland_key_04022022.pem                                                                                                                                              185
Ireland_Cert_New_26112021.pem                                                                                                                                         115
Ireland_Key_New_26112021.pem                                                                                                                                          115
israel_prod_cert_11012023.pem                                                                                                                                         526
israel_prod_key_11012023.pem                                                                                                                                          526
lt_sergey_cert_01102023.pem                                                                                                                                           789
lt_sergey_key_01102023.pem                                                                                                                                            789
MATEJ_MUHA_cert_06102021.p12                                                                                                                                           64
neztsw_cert_16072023.pem                                                                                                                                              712
neztsw_key_16072023.pem                                                                                                                                               712
nz_customs_cert_01102022.pem                                                                                                                                          424
poland_keystore_12112021.jks                                                                                                                                          101
romania_rsakey_05102025.pem                                                                                                                                          1524
slovenia_cert_05102025.pem                                                                                                                                           1524
slovenia_gov_cert_21012025.pem                                                                                                                                       1267
slovenia_rsakey_05102025.pem                                                                                                                                         1524
```

I have tried to use the **Where-Object** to get the less than but struggling to just get the number showing (I don't want to see count, average etc as shown below)

```
$result2a | Where-Object Days -le 30 | Measure-Object


Count    : 0
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```

I've tried to remove the Measure-Object but returns blank. Can somebody help point me where I am going wrong to just show the count of those certificates which are less than 30 days.

```
$result2a | Where-Object Days -le 30
```

Comment: Look at the `Days` column in the table-formatted output - _none of your certificates have 30 days or less_ (lowest value is 46) - `Where-Object` is clearly doing its job correctly :)

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen yes its doing it correctly, but I just want the ouput to be 0 or whatever the number might be. Not with the additional count / average etc

Comment: `$result2a | Where-Object Days -le 30 | Measure-Object |Select -Expand Count` or `$result2a | Where-Object Days -le 30 | Measure-Object |ForEach Count`

Comment: Perfect thank you @MathiasR.Jessen :D